# Failed importing a module in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I'm trying to import `mathquill4quill` using require function. The package has already been added to dependencies and automatically also to `package-lock` file so I was thinking everything was fine but when I try to import this module I get

> Error: Cannot find module 'mathquill4quill'.

The package.json file and package-lock.json are:

```
"dependencies":{
    "mathquill4quill": "latest"
}
```

and

```
"mathquill4quill": {
      "version": "0.1.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/mathquill4quill/-/mathquill4quill-0.1.3.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-/1lWllV228K2peFBJCPOU/PZaciPtq6mXIp+b78ZrLscow3ZquPLeuA8UjMoxbooJrWdRTXr2DBQMBFyNVwxYw=="
    }
```

How can I solve?

**edit:**

the import code is:

*index.html*

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

*bundle.js*

```
(function(){function r(e,n,t){function o(i,f){if(!n[i]){if(!e[i]){var c="function"==typeof require&&require;if(!f&&c)return c(i,!0);if(u)return u(i,!0);var a=new Error("Cannot find module '"+i+"'");throw a.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",a}var p=n[i]={exports:{}};e[i][0].call(p.exports,function(r){var n=e[i][1][r];return o(n||r)},p,p.exports,r,e,n,t)}return n[i].exports}for(var u="function"==typeof require&&require,i=0;i<t.length;i++)o(t[i]);return o}return r})()({1:[function(require,module,exports){


var Quill = require('quill');
var mathquill = require('mathquill4quill');

}

// code
)
```

the first function is used to check the import existence

Comment: Can you write the import code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the :
var Quill = require('quill');
var mathquill = require('mathquill4quill');

above your function and not bellow